# Getting the primary key value in the current result of the select query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

As you can see, I have these tables 
[Salary_grades](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPpxP.png) 
And 
[Teachers_salary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnmlY.png)
, the teacher_id is the foreign key of the teachers table that I will get in the different database.

I tried this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM teachers_salary 
LEFT JOIN salary_grades 
ON grade = (SELECT salary_grade FROM teachers_salary WHERE teacher_id = 3) 
WHERE teacher_id = 3;
```

and I get my desired result.

so my problem is I want to display all the information stored in the teacher_salary where their grade is equal to the grade in salary_grade table so I tried this query without the where clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM teachers_salary 
LEFT JOIN salary_grades ON grade = (SELECT salary_grade FROM teachers_salary);
```

and I get this Error :

> Subquery returns more than one row.

so how I can display all record with their salary_grades value is equal to the salary_grades.grade value?

Comment: The JOIN syntax is (usually) for joining columns together, so all you need to do is specify which column should be joined to which in the join. e.g. for your needs, you probably just need to do `select * from teaches_salary left join salary_grades on salary_grades.grade = teachers_salary.salary_grade`. NOTE: You should always be specific about which tables the columns you're joining are from (e.g. not just "columnA = columnB" but "tableX.columnA = tableY.columnB"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need sub-query for this

```
SELECT * 
FROM teachers_salary s
LEFT JOIN salary_grades g
ON s.salary_grade = g.grade
```

Comment: the table salary_grade don't have teacher_id field so I used this instead 
SELECT * 
FROM teachers_salary s
LEFT JOIN salary_grades g
ON s.salary_grade = g.grade; and I get what I want, thank you.